# glossaries-extra style (in text and list of acronyms)

Tags: acronyms, glossaries-extra

When I add `\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}` to my document the acronyms are not displayed as "Computer Aided Design (CAD)" for example but simply as "CAD". Furthermore the following warning is displayed:
`` Abbreviation style has been switched (glossaries) for category `acronym', (glossaries) but there have already been entries (glossaries) defined for this category. Unwanted (glossaries) side-effects may result ``

And is there a possibility to have the List of Acronyms list the long versions under each other, so that the first letter of each long entry is in a vertical line?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\newacronym{ac:cad}{CAD}{Computer Aided Design}
\newacronym{ac:cax}{CAx}{Computer Aided x}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    
\gls{ac:cad} \gls{ac:cad} \gls{ac:cax} \gls{ac:cax}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]   

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following changes in the MWE it all did work out:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries % put makeglossaries first

\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short} % put serabbreviationstyle second

\newacronym{ac:cad}{CAD}{Computer Aided Design}
\newacronym{ac:cax}{CAx}{Computer Aided x}
%\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}
%\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    
\gls{ac:cad} \gls{ac:cad} \gls{ac:cax} \gls{ac:cax}

\printglossary[style=super, type=\acronymtype] % added style "super"

\end{document}
```